get spectrum value with numpy only
I want to do a kind of frequency monitoring program, using rtl-sdr wrapper in python and numpy. This program must run in console mode, no graphic interface. I do not want to have a dependency with matplotlib or scipy, so I'm looking for a pure python and numpy solution.
I know how to read data from the rtl-sdr dongle (for example, centered at 446MHz with a sample rate of 250kHz should give me a spectrum from 445,875MHz to 446,125MHz).
But how to get this spectrum data ? How to compute the power of 80 linear bands in this range (freq resolution will be 3,125kHz) on data sampled for 100ms ?
I know I have to read 25000 samples (100ms at 250kHz), but I do not know how to compute the frequency power in numpy only.
Here is my skeleton code. the get_spectrum() function is what I want to do, but all the attempt I made with numpy (based on fft) where probably wrong because results were inconsistent (nothing special happens when I transmit on this frequency).
import numpy as np
from rtlsdr import RtlSdr

def get_spectrum( samples, sample_rate, freq_resolution):
  # TODO :)
  return [0,1,2,3,4]
  
sdr = RtlSdr()
sdr.sample_rate = 250_000
sdr.center_freq = 446_000_000
sdr.gain = 40
duration = 0.100# in second
sdr.read_samples(2048) # get rid of initial empty samples
while(True):
  samples = sdr.read_samples(duration * sdr.sample_rate)
  spectrum = get_spectrum(
    samples = samples,
    sample_rate = sdr.sample_rate,
    freq_resolution = sdr.sample_rate / 80) # to be drawn in a 80 columns terminal
  # normalize data for easy visualization
  min_val = np.min(spectrum)
  max_val = np.max(spectrum)
  scaled_data = 9 * ((spectrum - min_val) / (max_val - min_val))
  for i in scaled_data:
      v = int(i)
      print(int(i), end='')
  print() 

For my use case, the power level have not to be accurate, no need for a real scientific unit. It is only to be able to visualize and compare power of each frequency.
I know it is related to FFT and/or Power Spectral Density, but i dont know how to do it only in Numpy.

You can write your own power spectrum function purely using NumPy and employing, e.g., Welch's method, as shown below. In the example construct a complex valued input vector, to mimic what sdr.read_samples should return.
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dur = 0.1
sr = 250_000
center_freq = 446_000_000

# generate some complex samples
nsamples = int(dur * sr)
samples = np.random.randn(nsamples) + 1j * np.random.randn(nsamples)

def psd(data, nfft=80, overlap=0.5):
    """
    A Welch's method-based power spectrum function purely using
    numpy for complex input. This returns the averaged power not
    the power spectral density (although that just requires an
    an additional normalisation factor).
    """

    # number of samples to overlap consecutive FFTs
    noverlap = int(nfft * overlap)

    # create a window function
    window = np.hanning(nfft)
    winpow = window.sum()**2

    # generate ffts
    fftpower = np.zeros(nfft)
    idx = 0
    count = 0
    while True:
        inputdata = data[idx: idx + nfft]

        if len(inputdata) < nfft:
            # zero pad the final piece
            inputdata = np.pad(inputdata, ((0, nfft - len(inputdata))))

        # perform FFT on windowed data
        fftdata = np.fft.fft(inputdata * window)

        # sum FFT power
        fftpower += np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(fftdata))**2

        # move on index
        idx += nfft - noverlap
        count += 1

        if idx >= len(data):
            break

    # get the average power
    fftpower /= (count * winpow)

    return fftpower

nbins = 80
power = psd(samples, nfft=nbins)

# frequencies (MHz)
freqs = (np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(nbins, d=(1 / sr))) + center_freq) / 1e6

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(freqs, power)
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency (MHz)")

Note that, if you wanted to, you could avoid the while loop by using some NumPy trickery, as is done in the function used by Matplotlib's psd function here, e.g.,
def psd(data, nfft=80, overlap=0.5):
    """
    A Welch's method-based two-sided power spectrum function purely
    using numpy for complex input. This returns the averaged power not
    the power spectral density (although that just requires an
    an additional normalisation factor).
    """

    # number of samples to overlap consecutive FFTs
    noverlap = int(nfft * overlap)

    # create a window function
    window = np.hanning(nfft)

    # generate spectrogram
    if len(data) < nfft:
        np.pad(data, ((0, nfft - len(data))))

    # use stride tricks to get a sliding window view
    sldata = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
        data, nfft, axis=0
    )[::nfft - noverlap].T

    # perform FFT on windowed data
    fftdata = np.fft.fft(sldata * window.reshape((-1, 1)), n=nfft, axis=0)

    # get mean FFT power over spectrogram
    winpow = window.sum()**2  # preserve power
    fftpower = np.abs(
        np.fft.fftshift(np.conj(fftdata) * fftdata) / winpow 
    ).mean(axis=-1)

    return fftpower


Thank you, seems to do the trick. Because this psd function will be in a loop, I optimized it by moving the window outside the func. There is some work to do to normalize the data I presume. See result here if interested.

I've updated the answer to include a more efficient version using the NumPy stride_tricks, and adding in a scaling to account for power lost from the window. The new version is about 10 times faster than the version with the while loop.

Thank you for the update. Do you know what is the unit of the frequency power ? it vary from 0.0 (no antenna, 0 gain) to 0.6 (very strong FM station)

It will just be the square of whatever amplitude units the input is in. Looking at https://pyrtlsdr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rtlsdr.html#rtlsdr.rtlsdr.BaseRtlSdr.read_samples it says that the sample are normalised to be between +/-1, so there is no appropriate unit. You'd just have to say that the values are proportional to the power.
